# C++ OR operator refuses to stop only when 1st part is true

Tags: c++

I've been playing with some tutorials and I've reached a part where I use a "while", the OR operator stops only when the 1st condition is true and doesn't when the 2nd condition is, even though the 2nd condition has been a true for some loops.

```
while (humanCount > 0 || skeletonCount > 0)
{
    cout << "Humans left: " << humanCount << " | Skeletons left: " << skeletonCount << "\n";
    if (currentTurn == 0) // Human Attack
    {
        if (rollChance(randomNum) >= 0.5f)
        {
            skeletonCurrentHealth -= rollDamage(randomNum);
            if (skeletonCurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                skeletonCount--;
                skeletonCurrentHealth = skeletonMaxHealth;
            }
        }
        currentTurn = 1;
    }
    else // Skeleton Attack
    {
        if (rollChance(randomNum) >= 0.7f)
        {
            humanCurrentHealth -= rollDamage(randomNum);
            if (humanCurrentHealth <= 0)
            {
                humanCount--;
                humanCurrentHealth = humanMaxHealth;
            }
        }
        currentTurn = 0;
    }
}
```

From the print what I get is something like:

```
Humans left: 3 | Skeletons left: 5
Humans left: 3 | Skeletons left: 4
Humans left: 3 | Skeletons left: 3
Humans left: 2 | Skeletons left: 3
Humans left: 2 | Skeletons left: 2
Humans left: 2 | Skeletons left: 1
Humans left: 2 | Skeletons left: 0
Humans left: 2 | Skeletons left: -1
Humans left: 1 | Skeletons left: -1
Humans left: 1 | Skeletons left: -2
Humans left: 1 | Skeletons left: -3
Humans left: 0 | Skeletons left: -3
Humans have won!
```

I'm kind of lost here, would love some help what did I do wrong.

Comment: while does not stop when the condition is true, it stops when the condition is false, in your case when both are parts are false. Read up on D'morgans law

Comment: Or is the wrong option here, you want a while (humancount > 0 && skeletoncount > 0)

Answer (score 5):

The OR-operator (`||`) returns true when at least one condition is true. In your case that would mean that both skeletons and humans need to be 0 or less for the loop to stop. Or rather it will continue if at least one of them is > 0.
You get the correct behavior when you use AND (`&&`), which only returns true when all operands are true.

Answer (score 5):

`while (humanCount > 0 || skeletonCount > 0)`
Means your code will continue to execute if EITHER of the terms is true. If skeletonCount = -4 and humanCount = 2 then one of the terms is still true so your code will continue to run. You want to use an AND `&&`